Discontinuity in Fanning friction factor in pipe when compared with drag coefficient on sphere
Fanning friction chart (as a function of Reynolds number) has a gap for a range of Reynolds number ($2000 < Re <4000$). Notable part is that gap cannot be joined with a smooth curve.

Compare this with a graph of the drag coefficient for a sphere. Note that there is no discontinuity in the drag coefficient.

How to explain the differences?

There is a clear discontinuity for the Fanning friction factor chart. The drag coefficient, on the other hand, is continuous

Critical Reynolds for the two geometries should obliviously be different. Question is there any way to explain why the critical Reynolds number for pipe flow is higher ($Re \sim 2000$) compared to sphere geometry ($Re \sim 1$)? In other words, would you be surprised if the critical Reynolds number for sphere was $10^4$ and for pipe flow $1$?


In fact, I would assume that such a gap should be for the drag coefficient for a sphere. As fluctuations of velocity and pressure field dampened to a lesser degree for the sphere (a relatively open geometry compared to a pipe)

The top plot is for flow in pipes and the bottom plot is flow across a sphere.  The two graphs are dealing with different geometries and turbulence, so there is no valid mathematical comparison.  And note - NO ONE, in at least the last 100 years, has been able to mathematically quantify turbulence, and I doubt that anyone ever will.

The fluid flows are completely different.  Why would you expect the drag coefficients/friction factors to be the same?
